# MS Access 2013, where is my toolbar and vba editor?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I am trying to get into the codes for my access file, my file has no toolbar options, do I have some light version of access or something? or is this file locked? Was trying to get to full options menu seen here :[Where'd my ribbon tabs go in ms-access?](https://superuser.com/questions/820368/whered-my-ribbon-tabs-go-in-ms-access#:~:text=You%20have%20to%20navigate%20to,to%20the%20full%20options%20page).&text=Press%20Alt%20%2B%20F11%20to%20activate%20the%20Visual%20Basic%20interface.&text=Then%20press%20F5%20to%20run,and%20your%20toolbar%20will%20reappear).

but cannot get there. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might have to enable the extra tabs: view in word, should be similar in Access: https://superuser.com/questions/566992/how-to-inspect-view-an-excel-macro-before-enabling-macros-for-a-sheet/566999#566999

Comment: does not seem to work Moku

Comment: Do you actually have the full version of Access or just the Runtime?

Comment: Looks like run time, why?

Comment: Because the runtime is only for viewing databases, it has no editing features nor access to anything important such as the designer or developer tools. So the answer is basically: "You need a full version of Access, the runtime is not enough."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [Access Runtime](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/download-and-install-office-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9).

The runtime is only for viewing database applications, it has no editing features nor access to anything important such as the designer or developer tools. In order to view the application you need a full version of Access, the runtime is not enough.